# Чому піски олешківські, а не олешські?

Tags: словотворення, милозвучність

Маємо місто Олешки і від нього названі Олешківські піски.

Також маємо місто Каховка і від нього назване Каховське водосховище. Зауважте, Каховське, а не Каховківське.

Може це через милозвучність, можливо *ш* і *с* поруч не дуже звучать чи є інша причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

| Скоротилися | Не скоротилися |
| --- | --- |
| Русанівка → Русанівський (не Русанівківський, Русанівкинський чи Русанівковський) | Олешки → Олешківський |
| Жмеринка → Жмеринський (не Жмеринківський, Жмеринкинський чи Жмеринковський) | Шостка → Шосткинський |
| Каховка → Каховський (не Каховківський, Каховкинський чи Каховковський) |  |

Здається мені, що різниця в тому, що в лівих трьох випадках ми вже маємо буквосполучення -ів-, -ин-, -ов-, що мають вигляд суфіксів присвійності (і додавати ще один такий суфікс не хочеться (навіть незважаючи на те, що можна було б уникнути повторення, використавши інший суфікс)).

Comment: [Буцький каньйон](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD) скоротився.

Comment: @Yola, так, виходить, що -ів-/-ин-/-ов- перед -ськ- у загальному випадку додавати необов'язково (навіть коли у слові немає власного -ів-/-ин-/-ов-; Житомир → Житомирський, а не Житомирівський, Житомиринський чи Житомировський; тобто, виходить, у відповіді я навів необхідну умову додавання -ів-/-ин-/-ов-, але не достатню). Виходить, у випадку Олешків і Шостки перепоною справді стає немилозвучність (ніхто не хоче казати «Олешцький» і «Шостцький»).

Comment: якщо ви перенесете це у відповідь, то я готовий її прийняти.